# onDonePress() for intro_slides implementation?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to edit the void `onDonePress()` function (the "demo" example from https://flutterappdev.com/2019/01/24/simple-and-configurable-app-introduction-slider-for-flutter/), however, my app is not doing what I am expecting it to do.

I wanted the "Done" button to redirect the user to a login page which I made in another dart file called `Login.dart`

This is my onDonePress implementation:

```html
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Slide> slides = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        backgroundImage: "images/1.png",
        backgroundImageFit: BoxFit.cover,
        backgroundOpacity: 0,
        backgroundOpacityColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        backgroundImage: "images/2.png",
        backgroundImageFit: BoxFit.cover,
        backgroundOpacity: 0,
        backgroundOpacityColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        backgroundImage: "images/2.png",
        backgroundImageFit: BoxFit.cover,
        backgroundOpacity: 0,
        backgroundOpacityColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }

  void onSkipPress() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
    );
  }

  void onDonePress() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new IntroSlider(
      slides: this.slides,
      onDonePress: this.onDonePress,
      onSkipPress: this.onSkipPress,
    );
  }
}
```

This is part of my `next.dart` file

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Login());

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: CompanyColors.pink[100],
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Welcome!'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //TextField: allows you to enter text with keyboard or onscreen keyboard
    final email = TextField(
```

Any ideas on why it is not going to the login page? When I press "Done" the screen stays the same. I also have included import `Login.dart` to my intro slides dart file.

Comment: if you have a `HomePage()` in `main.dart` why have you created `HomePage` in `login.dart` as well?

Comment: I do not have HomePage() in main.dart. In main.dart I have 
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget, sorry for the odd naming

Comment: instead of just `onDonePress` can you post code for whole widget?

Comment: Sure, I just edited it. Sorry, I'm a bit new to app development so any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that your `MyHomePage` class has a MaterialApp as parent

Comment: Otherwise I don't see a problem... but I'll have to test it manually to make sure what's wrong.

Comment: Should the MaterialApp you mention be in the StatelessWidget part of the code?

Comment: Doesn't matter if stateless or not, it must be the root widget. i.e. inside the first widget from `runApp()`

Comment: I have tried out your code and I can't reproduce the problem. Everything's working as expected.

Comment: Like when you press Done it redirects you to the login screen? How odd... are you also using IOS simulator?

Comment: It actually crashes now, so odd how it works for your implementation!

Comment: Oh it works! I wasn't returning a null when I was printing the Title at times so I had to fix the title in AppBar (which I did not include in my question, my apologies) to Text(widget?.title ?? ' ')

Thank you for your help it helped to know I was doing the function right!